# What do these words have in common? (Season 12, Episode 254)

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, connections-puzzle

Here are some chosen words from a large group:

> angel
> bat
> cling
> dog
> glass
> hatchet
> ice
> king
> knife
> lamp
> lancet
> lion
> lung
> noodle
> oil
> parrot
> pin
> pipe
> rainbow
> rock
> sand
> sun
> surgeon
> tile
> trigger
> turkey
> velvet
> viper

**Can you explain what they have in common?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All of these words:

> can be followed by the word **FISH** to make the name of a sea creature.

The full list is as follows, with Wikipedia links provided:

> [Angelfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pterophyllum), [Batfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batfish), [Clingfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gobiesocidae), [Dogfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squalidae), [Glassfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambassidae), [Hatchetfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gasteropelecidae), [Icefish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Channichthyidae), [Kingfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingfish), [Knifefish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_knifefish), [Lampfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lampfish), [Lancetfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lancetfish), [Lionfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pterois), [Lungfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lungfish), [Noodlefish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salangidae), [Oilfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oilfish), [Parrotfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parrotfish), [Pinfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagodon_rhomboides), [Pipefish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipefish), [Rainbowfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbowfish), [Rockfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rockfish), [Sandfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichodontidae), [Sunfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocean_sunfish), [Surgeonfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acanthuridae), [Tilefish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilefish), [Triggerfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triggerfish), [Turkeyfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dendrochirus_zebra), [Velvetfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velvetfish), [Viperfish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viperfish).

And here's the answer in visual form!

> [image]

Comment: For those wondering about the title, I believe it likely has no bearing on the puzzle itself and is intended purely as a joke, in the vein of "here's yet another connections puzzle" :)

Comment: Not sure if some of these would make it too obvious, but you could add (just off the top of my head) rot13(Oybj, Png, Pybja, Qbycuva, Unt, Zbax, Ent, Fvyire, Juvgr, Lryybj)

Comment: Stiv, you are right, it was intended as a joke ;D
@DarrelHoffman I found about 100 such names. I decided to choose only some least obvious.